# What Android devices are small screen size and high density?

Tags: android

According to the [Android screen sizes and densities stats](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html), 3.3% of devices are small screen size and high density (hdpi). What devices are these? I always thought that most small screen devices were low density (ldpi).

Just looking at the Motorola developer website, [all their small screen devices are low density](http://developer.motorola.com/products/?filters=1033,1040). Am I missing a (somewhat) popular class of devices or is the data wrong?

Comment: There is also an [Android StackExchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/) for non-programming related questions :)

Comment: This is programming related because the answer will help determine what resources to provide in apps for these class of devices.

Comment: Android Device Density list: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest I've run into is a Sony Xperia X10 mini. 2.5 inch screen at 160 dpi (240 x 320), so it's technically a small-screen medium-density device.

The screen is so physically small, however, that I find that it breaks the whole Android "density independence" model and I actually special case it to use smaller assets than I otherwise would for a 160 dpi screen, with the assumption that the user knows he has a tiny screen and that it is preferable that things appear tiny on it (as opposed to nothing ever really fitting).

Comment: So the Xperia X10 mini is a mdpi device? Moto devices with similar screen sizes and the same resolution are ldpi devices. And [this table on the Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing) seems to indicate this class of device should be classified as ldpi. I guess since this is a "generalized" dpi, it gives manufactures some leeway.

Comment: I read that table as saying it's mdpi (160 dpi is the nominal mdpi density). On the other hand, I see the table cell for that particular configuration is left blank - I don;t know what to make of that. Also, I have no idea what the SDK reports in terms of density class for it: at app startup I read the actual physical pixel density and the screen resolution and decide for myself what assets/sizes to use.

Comment: I guess I read the table a little backwards and looked at what density column the small, 240x320 cell was in. Anyway, it seems that manufacturers sometimes choose a density value that looks the best, instead of the one that is closest to the actual value.

Comment: The sony Xperia mini has 320 x 480 pixels and 3.0 inches -> 192ppi, as stated here: http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_ericsson_xperia_mini-3947.php. According to http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html, this is a small screen with hdpi.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a related question a while ago:

[Master list of high PPI mobile screens and how to detect/handle it via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094040/master-list-of-high-ppi-mobile-screens-and-how-to-detect-handle-it-via-css)

At the time, and even now, it seems that the only devices that declare their high density is iPhone 4.

There's lots of high density BlackBerry devices, but they don't declare it, so it's just makes your elements that much smaller. A bit frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

The Samsung Galaxy 550 is also working with small layout and drawable ldpi folder  ( 240x320 ldpi  )