# Media query not working for (min-width:321px)

Tags: iphone, css

I'm building a responsive design and everything is fine apart from I can't seem to target iPhone 3g users.

I've added the following media queries but the first one (max-width:320px) doesn't seem to work

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
// STYLES GO HERE
}

@media screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 640px) {
//STYLES GO HERE
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have a look at this post, perhaps it could give you a hint, I'm not sure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031482/how-to-target-iphone-3gs-and-iphone-4-in-one-media-query


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031482/how-to-target-iphone-3gs-and-iphone-4-in-one-media-query

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/a/15673397/2077405 should answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

Try max-device-width `(max-device-width: 320px)`; I haven't tried it specifically for non-retina display iPhones, but have found it to help when targeting the iPhone 4 specifically.