# Why isn't my media query for smaller breakpoints being implemented?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am writing a media query for a web-page and managed to write media queries for 480px and more. But when I write media query for 320px it doesn't work properly. I want to capture the portrait views of most of the mobiles( iphone4, iphone5,iphone3,asus galaxy 7,samsung galaxy sII, Samsung Galaxy s3 ) which is 320px. The webpage I created was working with landscape views in these devices but doesn't scale for portrait views. Can anybody please point out the error in the query. This is the media queries I used.

```
@media (max-width: 320px)
{
   html
   {
      font-size:0.1em;
   }
       
}
@media (max-width: 480px)
{
   html
   {
      font-size:0.20em;
   }
}
@media (max-width: 767px)
{
   html
   {
          font-size:0.38em;
   }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)
   {
       html
       {
           font-size:0.65em;
       }
   }
   
   @media (min-width : 980px) and (max-width:1025px)
   {
       html
       {
           font-size:0.7em;
       }
   }
```

For 320px I also tried with

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
{ /*Styles */}
```

and

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

But none of them is working.Am I doing anything wrong/missing something?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you don't have a min-width on your 480 styles, and since those styles come later in your stylesheet, they override anything you put before them.

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
   html {
      font-size:0.1em;
   }
}
@media (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px) {
   html {
      font-size:0.20em;
   }
}
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

**A**

```
@media (max-width: 320px)
{
   html { font-size:0.1em; }
}
```

**B**

```
@media (max-width: 480px)
{
 html { font-size:0.20em; }
}
```

Using the above, consider a 320px viewport.

**A and B** are **true**, as 320 hits the limit of A and falls well below the max of B. But since B overrides A by being declared later in the stylesheet, font-size is dictated by the later declaration -- B

Adding a `min-width:321px` requirement to **B** would force B to test false for the 320px viewport -- so font-size would stay at 0.1em until B became true (minimum width of 321px).

**EDIT (maybe a better way to think about it)**
Instead of using max, max, max, why not take advantage of the `min-width`, until you reach a UI that may be best served with a range (like a tablet)

```
/* Set a base */
html { font-size:62.5% }

/* iPhone landscape range */
@media (min-width:321px) and (max-width:480px) {
    html { font-size:1.2em }
}

/* larger than iPhone landscape, an in the iPad portrait range */
@media (min-width:481px) and (max-width:768px) {
    html { font-size:1.6em }
}

/* bigger than iPad portrait  */
@media (min-width:769px) {
    html { font-size:2em }
}
```